# google app engine, Google Apps and custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

If you have a google app engine application you want to have on a certain domain for this application, you control this domain but if this domain is used already used for e-mail (not on Google Business Apps), does this mean you have to switch your e-mail to Google Business Apps in order to have this domain for your google app engine application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have to add the domain to google apps, but you don't have to use google mail.

Comment: So if I understand I can have a different Google Apps Account domain setup, and a different domain for the app engine application itself?

Comment: if the domain is already in google apps you should be able to use it for the app engine application. If the domain is currently not registered as an google apps domain you have to register it to a google account.

Comment: so if I use xyz.com domain for e-mail, and I want xyz.com for app engine application, I don't have to have xyz.com for Google Apps e-mail? is this correct?

Comment: because i don't think I can use xyz.com for Gmail (under Business Apps account) and xyz.com under existing e-mail server (exchange or whatever). Correct me if I'm wrong or it depends on the DNS settings?

Comment: you don't have to use google mail and you don't have to change the mail dns settings if you want to use your old email service